# UIAlert View and Animation

Tags: xcode5, uiviewanimation

As we know Alert view is shown as modally. 
I am not sure if this is possible. I want to animation to start only when user press OK on Alert View

AlertView code:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search" message:@"Not Available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

Animation code :

```
    NSInteger tabBarIndex = 3;
UITabBarController *myTabBar = self.tabBarController;
UIView *searchView = myTabBar.selectedViewController.view;
UIView *aboutView = [[[myTabBar viewControllers] objectAtIndex:tabBarIndex] view];
//animation
[UIView transitionFromView:searchView
                    toView:aboutView duration:1
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                       if(finished)
                       {
                           myTabBar.selectedIndex = tabBarIndex;

                       }
                   }
 ];
```

is there anyway to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible.

Using `UIAlertView`'s delegate method: `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` you can check which button was pressed and start the animation when that happens.

Comment: Thx, I was at documentation. Had feeling after reading it. but was not sure let me try it out.

Comment: You must make sure your ViewController also conforms to UIAlertView delegate before that method will be called. If you alertView only has one button - the clickedButtonAtIndex value is 0. Let me know if you need more help. I use this delegate a lot in my app. Good luck and happy coding

Comment: Totally awesome. I cant believe I was so close. thanks a lot. Its perfect now. :)